# How to deny access for virtual directories in .htaccess for all IP, and accep for 1 IP?

Tags: linux, htaccess

When you need to deny access to folder for all IP you should to put .htaccess in this folder, which must contein:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.1.1.1
```

You can do it in virtual hosts like in this example:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/mysite/my_folder">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.1.1.1
</Directory>
```

But how can i solve this task, when my_folder is not exist and its virtual directory?

There .htaccess, that situated inn "mysite" folder (/var/www/html/mysite/.htaccess) :

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ - [F,L]
# if directory exist, use it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if not, sent requests to index.php
#RewriteRule . index.php <-- before
RewriteRule ^([^/].*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] # <-- after
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<Location>` instead of `<Directory>`.

```
<Location /my_folder/>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.1.1.1
</Location>
```

See document on sections for [Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html), [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html).